# colocar imagen dinámica en un reporte RDLC en WebForm c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagen, webforms, rdlc

Estoy haciendo un reporte, donde genero un código de barras en formato PNG. Intento colocarlo en un reporte RDLC (versión 15) con VS2019 (WebForm y c#), dicho archivo lo genero en un la carpeta "Image" del proyecto, sin embargo al correrlo, me genera el archivo, pero no lo coloca en la página.

La carpeta donde guardo los códigos de barra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La manera de como configuro la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El campo del DataSet

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
asi llamo el reporte

[image]

El código que genera el código de barras

[image: el recuadro es donde debería salir y no sale el código]